# In hapijs 'property register of undefined' is comming

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

Below is the packages i have taken while running hapi.js server
Packages are:

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "^4.0.11",                                           
    // dependencies i have taken 

    "hapi": "^16.6.2",
    "inert": "^4.2.1",
    "vision": "^5.3.2"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
//Init server
const server = new Hapi.Server();

//Add connection
server.connection({
    port:15000,
    host:'localhost'
});

//Home route

server.route({
    method:'GET',
    path:'/',
    handler:function(request,reply){
       reply('Hello world');
    }
});

//Static routes
server.register({
    register: require('inert')
},function (err) {
    if(err){
        throw err;

    }
});


//Vision templates
server.register(require('vision'),function (err) {
   if(err){
       throw err;
   }
   server.views({
       engines:{
           html:require('handlebars')
       },
       path:__dirname+'/views'
   });
});

// Start Server
server.start(function(err)  {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('Server started at:'+ server.info.uri);
});
```

This is a program from hapi.js which is a javascript framework.
I am getting property 'register' of undefined in vision and handlebars in node.js.

The error is 'property register of undefined'

Comment: @Xufox please see my code

Comment: Can u answer @Xufox

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are registrering your plugins the Hapi 17 way while using Hapi 16...

You should give at least the full error message

Comment: Got it already, i was missing the version of vision, it should be of 4 series.